# Setting three.js projection matrix direction

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I read following codes writing for webgl, and I want rewrite it using three.js. But I could not find any way to do so, please help me.

```
pMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.perspective(pMatrix,1.01,gl.drawingBufferWidth/gl.drawingBufferHeight, 10.0, 300000.0);
var eciMat = [1,  0,  0,  0,
           0,  0, -1,  0,
           0,  1,  0,  0,
           0,  0,  0,  1
           ];
mat4.mul(pMatrix, pMatrix, eciMat );
```

Answer (score 0):

Matrix classes are pretty sophisticated in Three.js, look at the docs here: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix4

Here's how I would write it in Three.js

```
// Arguments are fov, aspect, near, far
var perspectiveMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makePerspective(30, 1, 0.01, 20);

var eciMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
eciMatrix.set(1,  0,  0,  0,
              0,  0, -1,  0,
              0,  1,  0,  0,
              0,  0,  0,  1);

var resultMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
resultMatrix.multiply(eciMatrix);
resultMatrix.multiply(perspectiveMatrix);
resultMatrix.multiply(perspectiveMatrix);

console.log(resultMatrix);
```

Comment: eciMatrix seems make axis rotate to Earth-centered inertial. Within three.js i found a camera attribute projectionMatrix, how should i assosiate resultMatrix with projectionMatrix? projectMatrix's elements copy seems incorrect.

Comment: Camera's projectionMatrix should be the result of the makePerspective call. Yep eciMatrix is a 90 degree rotation, was that not the intention? What was your intention? I simply tried to rewrite your code with Three.JS classes.